# convergence error codes in nlminb -- where stored?

Tags: r

I am building a *Monte Carlo* simulation for the purpose of power estimation, and I need to run 10,000 iterations, each of which involves fitting a bunch of mixed linear & logistic models to data I generate.  Once in a blue moon I get an error like this:

> nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1 ; message = iteration limit
>   reached without convergence

I gather from Googling the error that this is common and probably a function of my data (since it does not happen on most runs through the simulation program).  However, it is a pain because it makes my simulation crash and I can lose days worth of runtime.  I would like to make the program more robust by adding some error-handling to it, but I don't know where the *"convergence error code"* is stored, if anywhere.

Checking the manual pages for lme, lmeObject, and nlminb didn't really help.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/253908

Answer (score 1):

That sounds more like a warning than an error. The "convergence" element of the list that `nlminb` returns will be 0 for successful convergence. I would ask whether you might want to increase the "iter.max" element in the control list. This information is on the help page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm not sure this is what I need, though -- in 10,000 simulations of complicated data, I'm likely to run into some sets such that my model won't converge, which is why I'm looking to build in exception-handling rather than just trying to prevent the convergence problems themselves.

As I understand it, the distinction between an error and a warning is that errors will stop the program and warnings will only set a warning flag (unless you set an option to halt on all warnings -- which I haven't).  Is that right?  My program not only sets a warning flag, it also stops.

Comment: But... it is something you are doing _after_ the call that is causing an error. As you say a warning will not halt execution. Use traceback() after the error is thrown and figure out what is the root cause. Is some other program calling `nlminb`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  I'd love to be able to trigger the error more reliably -- do you happen to know what properties of datasets lead them to fail to converge?  I spent some time yesterday trying specifically to generate perverse data so I could interrogate the error further, but, perversely, failed.

Comment: If you want to force it to fail to converge you can also use the control parameters.This is code from the help page which I have rigged to fail: `x <- rnbinom(100, mu = 10, size = 10);
 hdev <- function(par) {
    -sum(dnbinom(x, mu = par[1], size = par[2], log = TRUE))
 }
;nlminb(c(9, 12), hdev, control=list(iter.max=1))`

Comment: @user1195893 is your question answered? If not, please make clear, otherwise accept.

Comment: Sorry about this -- I hadn't logged on in a bit.  This isn't the answer I was looking for -- I still think it should be possible to find out how to grab the result of a failure to converge; why does the state of failing-to-converge even have a numeric value if I can't extract and use it, you know -- but I can't say that DWin is wrong, per se.  The next error I ran into wound up being something else entirely, so I abandoned this line of error-handling altogether and just went with restarting the program every time it crashes.  Now rounding on 8,000 of 10,000...